# Add a user to xmpp group or in muc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, xmpp

I want to add 4 members (who are already users in oprefire) to a group. 
I want to add them without user permission nor sending invitation

Right now i am inviting a user using this code:

```
[sender inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"keithoys"] withMessage:@"Greetings!"];
```

**Is there some another way to achieve this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding participants to XMPP chat rooms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098075/adding-participants-to-xmpp-chat-rooms)

Answer (score 0):

When user send request to other user, the following delegate method is called:

```
-(void)xmppMUC:(XMPPMUC *)sender roomJID:(XMPPJID *)roomJID didReceiveInvitation:(XMPPMessage *)message{

    roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
    xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc]
                initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage
                                jid:roomJID
                      dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom activate:[self xmppStream]];

    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    //Now add user to the group directly without prompting them
    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:[xmppStream myJID].user history:nil];
}
```

I've only written the code, if you need explanation, i'll.

Comment: Hello @the_UB, How to retrieve data from roomMemoryStorage?

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve data?

Comment: I have to show list of rooms (that a user is owner or member of) in a tableView. then I have to show the message history on chat screen. Like we do for single user chat. I am  stuck at this. Please suggest me how can I save and retrieve data from core data .